# DICOM using dcmtk in a webpage

Tags: html, dicom

I have a PACS server running [Conquest](http://ingenium.home.xs4all.nl/dicom.html). Then, I need to choose the list of studies and series. I was using dcmtk for standalone applications. Now, basic operations like: select a study, select a serie, obtain the patient's information and obtain the data should work on a webpage.

I prefer to use some kind of "lightweight" server. Any idea to do that? to create simple queries over a PACS server using the DICOM protocol?

Could you suggest me any forums, pages, ideas or libraries?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is a bit late to answer your question, but, anyway, I consider this could be interesting to you.

I had a similar problem since I wanted to create a html5 dicom viewer able to connect to any PACS. So, I needed to perform queries to the Pacs. I ended up developing something like a gateway or webservice to get information about patients, studies and series of Dicom objects stored in the Pacs.

Now, this tool has been made publicly available on github.

Have a look at the, since I consider that it can be what you are looking for:

[dcmgw](https://github.com/jap1968/dcmgw): Dicom Gateway

[medview](https://github.com/jap1968/medview): html5 Dicom viewer

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really answer your exact question, but something like this already exists: check out [Ovyiam](http://oviyam.raster.in/)

> Oviyam is a web based DICOM Viewer. Using standard DICOM protocols patient lists can be queried, particular series or studies retrieved and be displayed as JPEG images in your browser. Oviyam will work with any DICOM server that supports WADO (Web Access to DICOM Persistent Objects).

Comment: Thanks, I checked Oviyam a few days ago. I think that my solution can be solved using the [dcm4chee]http://www.dcm4che.org/ libraries, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I think that [Orthanc](http://www.orthanc-server.com/) would be particularly well suited to your case. Orthanc is a lightweight, open-source DICOM server that comes with a REST API to access its content.